# Is asking for an article from an old computing periodical on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

As a case in point, I am looking for an article from an issue of PCW from 1982 (but I don't know which month) which related to generating mazes/dungeons using pseudo random seeds, what I think are called *procedural dungeon maps*.

There isn't (currently) a complete archive of the PCW magazines on the web at the moment, for example, as discussed here, ["Personal Computer World" magazine -1980's - pdfs?](http://www.amibay.com/showthread.php?51596-quot-Personal-Computer-World-quot-magazine-1980-s-pdfs)). There are a few snippets available on archive.org, see [Personal Computer World search](https://archive.org/search.php?query=subject%3A%22personal%20computer%20world%22), but that is about it.

Would it be on-topic to ask if someone has a copy of that article, and if they could provide a scan of it, as an answer?

---

As an aside, I am pretty sure that the same edition of PCW that has this random generated dungeon article, also has the advertisement that I am asking about in [Largest memory peripheral for Sinclair ZX81?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11029/largest-memory-peripheral-for-sinclair-zx81)

Answer (score 12):

### Yes

It's retro, and computing-related. We've got questions asking for manuals and documentation; I don't see how this is different.

---

Ignore the diamond, please. Look at the vote counter instead. I'm not an authoritative source.

Comment: Seconded. It clearly is.

Comment: I would tend to agree.  While on the surface it may look like a link request, the example question is actually primarily asking for which issue of the magazine the article originally appeared in.  That *is* something that can have a definitive, non time-sensitive answer that won't age out with dead links.

Comment: @mnem - whilst knowing which issue the article was in would be nice, I am really asking for a scan - assuming that there are no copyright issues...

Comment: @Greenonline If its a link-only answer you're looking that's not what StackExchange is for.  The question should be worded so that the answers have continued usefulness even if any links in the answer go dead.  Stack Exchange sites are meant primarily to serve as long-term references.

Comment: @mnem - a scan is not a link. A `.png`, or `.jpg` file included in the answer.

Comment: @mnem This is true. However, images hosted on i.stack.imgur.com are generally considered to be part of the answer.

Comment: @Greenonline  Good point.  I hadn't thought about someone attaching scans of the entire article into an answer.